# Angular: ternary operator possibilities to concat multiple terms

Tags: angular

I am using the ternary operator and have 2 questions about it.

e.g.

```
(click)="check () ? doA () : doB ()"
```

**1st:**

I like to expand it.

```
doaA ()   ----->   doA (); return false;
```

but that is only working if I put it in a wrapper function.
But I like to have it in ternary.

I tried

```
doA(); return false   // error
doA(); false;         // error
doA() && false        // think it is not evaluation because must be false
```

Any idea how I can put that in pure ternary operator without wrap it in a function?

The return must be false because the click should deactivate a ahref-link.

**2nd:**

I have some terms that do not have the "else". I think the operator must have the else branch to by syntax-correct. What is the common way to mark the "else" to be irrelevant?
Today is use '' but do not know if thats a good idea.

```
(click)="check () ? doA (): ''"
```

Comment: Just use `if` instead of ternary...

Comment: I appreciate any advice. So calling components function is not a good idea?

Comment: @HiWorld - What do you mean? Calling component methods in [event binding](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#event-binding---event-) is correct.

Comment: ternary is meant for if/else when the operation is supposed to be one line. so you can do a ternary with function calls, if you really want to use a ternary but an if/else statement might be best. also, why do you want a return false? you are calling a `(click)` function which generally should be a void

Comment: @ConnorsFan - very sorry. You are right

Comment: The click is in an a-href. Lets say in mode A it should behave normal (execute click AND follow the link). But in mode B it should only execute click. For that I need to return false to make it not follow the href-link.

Answer (score 3):

If I understood you correctly, you can achieve this by writing

`(click)="check() && doA()"`

so if `check()` returns **true** `doA()` will run next - otherwise it will just do nothing.