# From html file call a function based on condition without using *ngIf

Tags: angular

I want to call 2 functions in a single `<input type="text" (focusout)="">` based on a condition.
I don't want to use `*ngIf else` conditions.

**Example**
component.ts file i have declared 1 variable like

```
isCall = true;     
functionA(){}
functionB(){}
```

My `component.html` file is as follow

```
<input type="text" (focusout)="">
```

I want to call these 2 functions based on `isCall` from `(focusout)=""` event.
Suppose `isCall` variable is `true` then I want to call `functionA()` else `functionB()`
How can I call these function based on the condition?

Comment: use ternary operator as answered below. here is stackoverflow link  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hhbmyr?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular: ternary operator possibilities to concat multiple terms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52592790/angular-ternary-operator-possibilities-to-concat-multiple-terms)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call two functions by using **ternary operator** based on condition.

```
<input type="text" (focusout)="isCall ? functionA() : functionB() ">
```

[Here is solution on stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sjsrch)

Answer (score 1):

You can use ternary operator `? :` and based on condition you can call `functionA()` or `functionB()` like below.

**component.html**

```
<input type="text" (focusout)="isCall ?  functionA() : functionB()">
```

**component.ts**

```
 functionA() {
    console.log('HelloA');
  }

   functionB() {
    console.log('HelloB');
  }
```

**[Here is solution on stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hhbmyr?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)**

Hope this will help!

Answer (score 1):

> Solution 1

```
<input type="text" (focusout)="isCall? functionA(): functionB()">
```

> Solution 2

**in component.ts**

```
myFunction() {
 if(isCall)
  functionA()
 else
 functionB()
}
```

**in component.html**

```
<input type="text" (focusout)="myFunction()">
```

Comment: your 1st solution is use full

Answer (score 0):

In your ts file you can have a function like below

```
handleFocusOut(){
    if(isCall){
    functionA()
    }else {
    functionB()
    }  
}
```

and from the html, always call **handleFocusOut()** method.

```
<input type="text" (focusout)="handleFocusOut()">
```